# How to export multiple .csv-files?

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes of different dimensions that follow the naming scheme "data_x". I want to export them as .csv-files following a similar naming scheme.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149736/how-to-export-multiple-csv-file-in-r) but it relates to dataframes of the same dimensions. This is what I tried:

```
my_list <- (list = ls()[grep("^data", ls())])

data_list <- as.list(my_list)

bindFn <- function(i, data_list){
  sapply(data_list, '[[', i)
}

for(i in names(data_list)) write.csv(bindFn(i, data_list), paste0("data_",i, ".csv"), row.names=F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls()` has `pattern` argument to get the object name based on specific pattern in the data. You may try -

```
my_list <- ls(pattern = '^data')

purrr::imap(mget(my_list),
             ~write.csv(.x, sprintf('data_%s.csv', .y), row.names = FALSE))
```

To keep it completely in base R -

```
tmp <- mget(my_list)
Map(function(x, y) write.csv(x, y, row.names = FALSE), tmp, 
                   sprintf('data_%s.csv', names(tmp)))
```

where `mget` returns a named list of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

```r
purrr::walk(my_list, ~ write_csv2(get(.), str_c(., ".csv")))
```

Comment: You mean `write.csv2`?

Comment: `readr::write_csv2` is better.